# Convertir un fecha tipo string a formato ISODate de MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito almacenar las fechas contenidas en un objeto JSON en un formato que me asegure que será válido en cualquier escenario que se usen y el formato elegido es ISODate.

Inicialmente intenté crear un objeto `Date()` y la función `.toISOString()` para mi objeto, pero los resultados no son correctos:

- Si tengo una fecha como `02/01/2017 08:09:45 AM` que corresponde a (02 de enero de 2017), pasa lo siguiente:

  - Si uso `new Date(tramite.fecha_tramite)` obtengo `Wed Feb 01 2017 08:09:45 GMT-0600 (CST)`
  - Si uso `new Date(tramite.fecha_tramite).toISOString()` el resultado es `2017-02-01T14:09:45.000Z`
- Si tengo una fecha como `23/06/2017 02:58:36 PM` (6 de junio de 2017) entonces obtengo un error:

  ```
  Invalid Date
  /Volumes/datos/Proyectos/convertir-tramites/index.js:40
      console.log(`${new Date(tramite.fecha_afecta_ln).toISOString()}`)
                                                       ^

  RangeError: Invalid time value
  ```

Lo que necesito es convertir **`02/01/2017 08:09:45 AM`** en **`2017-01-02T14:09:45.000Z`**.

Este es un objeto JSON típico con el que hago pruebas:

```
{
    "FOLIO": "1738163100007",
    "estatus": "ENTREGADA",
    "causa_rechazo": "",
    "mov_solicitado": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "mov_definitivo": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:32:47 AM",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:42:40 AM",
    "fecha_reg_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 10:09:19 AM",
    "fecha_cancelado_mac": "",
    "fecha_rechazado": "",
    "fecha_cancelado_mov_post": "",
    "fecha_alta_pe": "02/01/2017 10:09:43 AM",
    "fecha_actual_pe": "02/01/2017 10:09:41 AM",
    "fecha_reinc_pe": "",
    "fecha_existoso": "02/01/2017 10:09:43 AM",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "02/01/2017 05:01:56 PM",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": "",
    "fecha_cpv_creada": "02/01/2017 05:01:42 PM",
    "fecha_registrada_mac": "09/01/2017 09:35:05 AM",
    "fecha_disponible": "09/01/2017 09:49:48 AM",
    "fecha_entregada": "23/01/2017 10:59:51 AM",
    "fecha_afecta_ln": "23/01/2017 02:58:36 PM"
}
```

Y con estos son mis experimentos:

```
console.log(`La fecha pelona: ${tramite.fecha_tramite}`)
console.log(`Usando solo Date(): ${new Date(tramite.fecha_tramite)}`)
console.log(`Usando Date().toISOString(): ${new Date(tramite.fecha_tramite).toISOString()}`)
```

En Python puedo usar la función [**`strftime`**](http://strftime.org), pero usando JavaScript y node, ¿cómo podría convertir una fecha tipo *string* a un objeto con el formato requerido?

Comment: No te compliques y usa [moment](https://momentjs.com). Solo encierras le pasas la fecha al constructor de moment y opcionalmente el formato actual, finalmente haces uso de format/parse para formatear/parsear la fecha en otro formato.

Comment: Para versiones posteriores se puede usar [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dice Gustavo, la mejor solución es MomentJS. Si bien SIEMPRE es mejor optar por una solución *vanilla JS*, en el caso de las fechas (sobre todo para las fechas en formato no-USA) esta es la mejor opción. En Node y usando node-moment (wrapper de Node para moment()):

```
const moment = require('node-moment');

//"fecha_alta_pe": "02javascript:void(0)/01/2017 10:09:43 AM"
console.log('Fecha ISO : ' + moment('02/01/2017 10:09:43 AM').toISOString());
//output -> 2017-02-01T10:09:43.000Z
```

Por supuesto debes primero instalar Moment via `npm install node-moment --save-dev` si quieres usar simplemente moment() (en una página web) puedes bajar MomentJS desde su sitio oficial.

Answer (score 1):

En moment pude ver que la conversión correcta se debería hacer para este ejemplo, así;

```
console.log('Fecha ISO : ' + moment('02/01/2017 10:09:43 AM', "DD-MM-YYYY").format());
```

el resultado;

> Fecha ISO : 2017-01-02T00:00:00-03:00